Do components "draw" current, or is it forced through them?
If you attach a typical LED to a 9V battery, the LED will burn out because there's too much current. If you add a resistor, it's fine.
You can charge your phone with a 1.0A charger, a 2.4A charger, and both work. Your phone doesn't "burn out." This had led me to believe that devices "draw" as much current as they could use, and it was attaching too high a voltage that caused them to burn out.
Now I'm confused again. Does anyone have a better way to explain it? I understand Ohm's law in as much as I understand the formula, but it seems it's the concept I don't grasp as well as I thought.

It depends on the component. A phone is not a "component" though, in the context of electrical engineering.

2.4A charger ... that power supply is able to supply up to 2.4 A without the output voltage sagging

voltage pushes current through a component ... a component does not suck current from a power supply, unless the component is another power supply, connected in reverse

The real world is complicated. This is why we try to Model it as simply as we can. A model tries to encapsulate the things we are interested in, while excluding, or hiding, or approximating things we don't care about. Remember that All Models are Wrong but some are useful.
Three of the simplest models we use in engineering are a pure ohmic resistor, a constant voltage source, and a constant current source. Slightly more complicated models are an ideal capacitor or inductor which have time-varying behaviour, or an ideal diode which is non-linear in its VI characteristics. When using these simple models, we can use words like draw and force. Go outside the validity of the models and they're not useful any more.
If you a connect a component to a voltage source V, it will draw the current it wants, given the constant voltage that the voltage source supplies across its terminals. If it's a resistor R, it will draw a current of V/R. An ideal diode will draw a current that's an exponential function of voltage - with a voltage a little above nominal it may draw orders of magnitude more current than nominal, and burn out. A capacitor will draw a pulse of current until it's charged. An inductor subject to a constant voltage will draw an increasing current, which will ramp up to as high as the voltage source will deliver, infinite given enough time and an ideal voltage source.
If you connect a current source to a component, it will force that current through it, the voltage being controlled by the component. If it's a resistor, it will develop a voltage of IR. The voltage across a capacitor will ramp up to infinity given time and an ideal current source. The voltage across an inductor will drop to zero once its current has matched that of the source.
A phone is not a simple component. A phone does whatever its firmware controls it to do. When you connect it to a power supply (it's a power supply, not a charger), it will interrogate the supply to see what its capabilities are. Depending on the impedance of certain pins in the interface, or responses to messages (or lack of them), it might draw a low, or high current, or even ask the supply to send a higher voltage.
Good approximations to a voltage source are a rechargeable battery, or a constant voltage power supply. An inductor with a current flowing through makes quite an effective current source, able to generate enough voltage to damage components or make sparks if you try to stop the current, which is why we protect relay and motor drivers with a low voltage path to conduct that current when we try to switch them off.

A 2.4 A charger is capable of supplying 2.4 A, but only if the load consumes it.
Similarly, when you plug into your AC power outlet, the load (eg light bulb) consumes power based on its characteristics, not on the maximum capability of the outlet.
More simply - a car that CAN drive at 200 km/h doesn't always go that fast!

Those are completely different things.
They are completely different loads, and you are already mixing voltages and currents.
Yes, 9V battery outputs 9V.
USB supply to phone outputs 5V.
But it is not a battery charger. The battery charger is inside the phone, the charger just uses the 5V as input supply.
The phone takes in as much current as it needs to charge the battery at some rate, so it takes what it needs.
The LED also takes what it needs.
The problem is that LED is a component that ideally will pass as much current there is availabe.
The LED is a diode and it has a property called foward voltage, i.e. the voltage it needs to turn on. Assume the diode is ideal so it does not conduct if you apply less voltage, and condcts when forward voltage is applied.
The problem is that the LED only needs say 3V to turn on, so there cannot be more than 3V over a LED. So if you applied 9V, you already have a math problem, as you cannot both have an ideal battery trying to pass as much current as necessary to set 9V over the LED, an the LED trying to pass as much current necessary to set 3V over the battery. Current will be infinitely high and there cannot be two components setting a different voltage to same node, so math does not work. Mathematically a resistor that drops the 6V over it, passing the amount of current necessary to drop 6V in the resistance will allow the circuit to work, be calculateable and set the current to some arbitrary value you want.
For the phone scenario, it's the same as mains voltage in your home. You have same mains voltage in all your receptacles. An 1A lamp will take 1A from socket and 2A hair dryer takes 2A from socket. If they are behind same 10A fuse, they only take 3A and you can apply up to 7A more loads of your choosing, like a computer taking up to 7A. And the computer does not take 7A all the time, just when it needs power for heavy computing, and consumes much less when sitting idle. If you add more load than 10A, the fuse will blow.
Phone chargers and phones can be smart. A phone can communicate/detect if it is connected to 1A or 2.4A charger and use all the current it there is available, so there is no overload and the battery can be charged slower or faster.
(The values are arbitrary examples).

Ohm's law only applies to 'ohmic' devices.

An element (resistor or conductor) that behaves according to Ohm's law over some operating range is referred to as an ohmic device (or an ohmic resistor) because Ohm's law and a single value for the resistance suffice to describe the behavior of the device over that range.

Wikipedia: Ohm's law
A smartphone may contain many ohmic components, but as a whole is a non-ohmic device.

The LED is non-ohmic too.


You can charge your phone with a 1.0A charger, a 2.4A charger, and
both work. Your phone doesn't "burn out."

It will burn if you tried to apply too much voltage to it just as an LED burns when you apply too much voltage.

This had led me to believe that devices "draw" as much current as they
could use, and it was attaching too high a voltage that caused them to
burn out.

Yes, too much voltage will cause anything to burn and no, a simple device (like a resistor or LED) doesn't have the intelligence to know how much current it can use. As with any electrical component or device, we have to be mindful of not applying too much voltage.


However, you can charge your phone with a 1.0A charger, a 2.4A charger, and both work. Your phone doesn't "burn out".


Does anyone have a better way to explain it?

Here's a water analogy for you:

Think of the charger as a water tank with a tap attached on it, and the phone as someone to be able to turn the tap head.
The tank's capacity in litres is the charger's output voltage (*), and the tap's max flowrate is the output current "capability" of the charger.
Let's also assume that the tank is always being filled by an infinite (theoretically) water source (mains) as long as it's present and the tank is smart enough to keep itself full (voltage regulator).

(*) In this imaginary world, the water tanks are classified based on their "heights" i.e. a tank with larger capacity is "taller", one with lower capacity is "shorter". This is an attempt to prevent the confusion that may possibly come from the water pressure.
Because the person is smart enough, it's capable of adjusting the waterflow by turning the tap head as per the requirements: If he/she wants more water (current) then turns the tap head more towards the full. So your phone can adjust the current draw as long as the charger and the tap are "capable" of delivering it. A spec like "5V / 2.4A" printed on the phone charger's label doesn't necessarily mean that it's going to push 5V / 2.4A regardless of the attached load. The 2.4A spec is the capability of it. So the tank's tap cannot deliver more than this level of waterflow.
A resistor on the other hand, is someone carrying a fixed-width pipe or hose. If this is attached to the bottom of a tank, water will flow with a fixed rate (because the tank is always being kept full). The larger (taller) the tank, the higher the flow (more current).

With the same analogy, you can think of a battery as a water tank but it's not being filled up. You can attach the fixed-size thing (resistor) to the bottom of the tank, but the flowrate will gradually decrease.
